# Generalized linear (mixed?) model with imbalanced nested data

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I am unsure how to optimally model a data set obtained from a crude experiment to compare performance of two plastic molding tools used to manufacture widgets. Widgets are tested and results are recorded as either a pass or fail.

Tool 1 has two molding cavities, A2 and B2, meaning that two widgets can be produced at once. Tool 2 has 16 cavities, but they are paired according to the letter prefix; for example, C1 and C2 are more similar to each other than C1 and F1. Tool 2 was also evaluated under two operating conditions: "previous" and "new". However, I only have data for five out of 16 cavities under the "previous" condition. Pass and fail counts grouped by Cavity are shown below:

```
Tool  Condition  Cavity  n_pass n_fail
1     Control    A2      177    2
1     Control    B2      168    1
2     New        C1      159    1
2     New        C2      160    1
2     New        D1      154    1
2     New        D2      176    3
2     New        F1      147    0
2     New        F2      168    0
2     New        G1      166    0
2     New        G2      166    0
2     New        P1      163    1
2     New        P2      172    0
2     New        R1      135    2
2     New        R2      175    1
2     New        S1      169    4
2     New        S2      171    2
2     New        T1      176    2
2     New        T2      148    0
2     Previous   C1      138    2
2     Previous   C2      23     0
2     Previous   F1      30     0
2     Previous   F2      21     1
2     Previous   G1      96     0
```

Based on the number of failures, I want to determine the best tool and operating condition, as well as the performance of each cavity.

Since the data is available as pass/fail, my first thought was to use logistic regression. I'm unsure how to correctly specify the model, however, given the imbalanced nested structure of the data.

My first attempt using brms was

```
formula = Fail ~ Tool + (1|Tool/Condition/Cavity)
fit = brm(formula, data=data, family=bernoulli, warmup=1000, iter=2000, chains=4, control=list(adapt_delta-0.99)
```

where Fail is a binary variable with 1 indicating a failure and 0 a pass.

There are divergent transitions that aren't resolved by increasing adapt_delta, and it would be difficult to come up with strong priors. Is my model correctly specified? Is there a better way of approaching this problem? Some sort of multiple comparisons for proportions?

Comment: You likely don't have enough failures here to make strong statistical arguments given the number of parameters you have.

Comment: I figured as much, based on some naive tests I did by treating each cavity as independent. I'm hoping a Bayesian model could help at least provide a stable model.

Comment: You should use a binomial family and use something like '(Fail, Pass + Fail) ~ Tool'. Right now, you are not including the information on how many passed attempts you've seen.

Comment: I don't have `brms` installed at the moment, but I checked with `glmer` from `lme4` and the correct invocation is `glmer("cbind(n_fail, n_pass + n_fail) ~ 1 + (1 | Condition) + (1 | Cavity)", family = "binomial", data = cav)`. If you use that, the observed differences are indeed consistent with no differences between any of the conditions. There could be some differences though, a Bayesian analysis is a good idea here.